# Change the start point of Facebook Page Ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, time-zone

Facebook says in docs, that Facebook Page Ads always start and end on midnight. In which timezone it is measured? Is there any way I can adjust this to my own timezone (or any other, I like to), to be able to have each day of my Facebook Page Ad campaign start and end at selected moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to [New Page Insights](https://www.facebook.com/2222FacesCom?sk=insights) and then  click on `Likes` tab, you'll see a text saying `Daily data is recorded in the Pacific time zone`, so I believe, that all Facebook Pages ads also starts and ends at midnight PT.

However, I have no idea, how to change this and if this is possible at all?